# Keyboard switching shortcut not always responding on Macbook Air M1 macOS 12.2

Tags: macos, keyboard, settings

The problem that drives me nuts is that when I switch languages by pressing <kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> it does not switch if I press it too quickly. It's the same with <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd>, too. The system simply does not respond to the key-presses that are too short. This is not a bug, it is by design. The problem can be solved by switching on the slow keys (**System Preferences** > **Accessibility** > **Keyboard** > **Hardware**) and setting the acceptance delay to the shortest option. Then I can switch the language as fast as I like and the capslock responds accurately, too. But then the key repeat speed setting (**System Preferences** > **Keyboard**) stops working (I prefer the fastest), and it is a pain to move the cursor while editing a text.

Is there a way to edit the Defaults or something to have low acceptance delay and high key-repeat speed at the same time?

Comment: How short is "too short"? I cannot press a key quickly enough for it not to be registered, and I can type at 300 chars per minute. Is this a problem only with Changing Language, or with key presses in general?

Comment: Changing language and Capslock. Other keys always register. With Slow Keys off I can consistently press Capslock fast enough for it not lo lock. With Slow Keys on and low acceptance delay I cannot.

Comment: I don't really care about Capslock -- it's just easy to test because it's one key and has a light on it. All I want is being able to go back and forth between languages while typing without having to stop, press the combination repeatedly and look at the status bar to verify that it finally did work.

Comment: @Okra Thank you for the question. This is precisely what I suffer from. It is good to know you are not alone with the problem. Did you find any solution? I have been fighting it for almost a year now, periodically searching online with no luck.

Comment: The only solution I know is the one I described. More of a trade-off. If you switch Slow Keys on and set the delay to minimum, the language switches properly but the key-repeat rate resets to standard.

Comment: Sounds like MacOS has some problem with language switching that is implicitly fixed by the "slow keys" setting. >This is not a bug, it is by design< Why do you think that it is not a bug?

Comment: Because I think this is a system made to reject accidental presses on TAB, CAPS, Power Key etc. My problem is only that this system made to ignore very short key presses conflicts with the "key repeat" setting. The conflict is a bug. Still unresolved, btw.